# Measure of non-measurable set is zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am working on a problem from Richard Bass' analysis, which to a slowpoke is just a jumbling of unrelated terms:

> Suppose that set $N$ is non-measurable as defined in Section 4.4. Show that $m(A) = 0$ if $A \subset N$, where $A$ is Lebesgue measurable. 
>   (Section 4.4 has this theorem: *Let $m^*$ be defined by the usual outer measure definition, where $\mathcal C$ is the collection of intervals that are open on the left and closed on the right and $\mathscr l ((a, b]) = b - a$. Then $m^*$ is not a measure on the collection of all subsets of $\mathbb R$.*)

Here are what I managed to salvage from the mess before my mind goes on strike: 
(1) Since $N$ is non-measurable per Section 4.4, which says that all subsets of $\mathbb R$ is non-measurable, then $N \subset \mathbb R.$ 
(2) Since $A \subset N$, isn't it $A \subset \mathbb R$ as well? 
(3) Since $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, then

$$\forall B \subseteq \mathbb R, \ m(B) = m(B \cap A) + m(B \cap A^c).$$

Please let me know how and where I should go from here. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Your point (3) holds only when $B$ is measurable, not for arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Does section 4.4 contain a definition of "non-measurable" (or of a particular set $N$)? With the usual meaning what you're being asked to show isn't true. For example, if we let $C$ be a non-measurable subset of $[1,2]$, then $N=C\cup[0,1]$ is still not measurable, but $A=[0,1]\subset N$ and is Lebesgue measurable with nonzero measure.

Comment: Thanks! You can look at the entire page from the link below, Bass's online book, page 30 - 31, and the problem is Exercise 4.13, page 35. Please let me know and thanks again. http://homepages.uconn.edu/~rib02005/real-analysis-04nov2011.pdf

Comment: The problem is stated for **the** particular set $N$ constructed in section 4.4.

Comment: @Tom : So, $N = \{ (a, b] \mid a, b \in \mathbb R \}$? $N \in \mathcal C$?

Comment: No, you need to read the definition inside the proof of theorem 4.15.

Comment: Note that the proof of 4.15 calls the non-measurable set it defines $A$ rather than $N$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Are you sure about your first comment? I think point 3 is precisely the Caratheodory condition for $A$ to be measurable, and it must hold for every $B\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @bartgol: The left-hand side of the equation says $m(B)$, which, by definition, is only even defined then $B$ is measurable.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I was thinking about the outer measure. The Caratheodory condition is formulated in terms of $m^*$. Which I guess is probably what the OP wanted to write?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The statement is for a particular $N$ constructed in that book.

The properties we need to use from $N$ is that its rational translations $N+r$ are disjoint and that $\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(N+r)\subset[-1,2]$.

Assume that $A\subset N$ is measurable.

This implies that $A+r$ are disjoint for $r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$. So 
$$3\geq m([-1,2])\geq m(\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(A+r))=\sum_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}m(A+r)=\sum_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}m(A)$$

This can only happen if $m(A)=0$.

> Notice this is the same as half of the proof of theorem 4.15. The only difference is that since $A$ is not all of $N$ we don't have the inclusion $\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(A+r)\supset[0,1]$ and therefore there is no inequality $\geq1$ from below preventing $m(A)=0$.

Comment: I am reading & digesting yours... I think on the 4th line from above, shouldn't it be "This implies that $A + r$ are disjoint for $r \in \mathbb Q$ ... " instead? Thanks again!

Comment: @A.Magnus Yes, $r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$.

Comment: In real setting, do you think I need to supply proofs to $N + r$ are disjoint and that $\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(N+r)\subset[-1,2]$? Or are they taken for granted?

Comment: It is up to you. At the very least you do need to convince yourself that those statements are true. Those are claimed and used in the proof of theorem 4.15. The first follows directly from the definition of $N$, the second follows from $N\subset[0,1]$ and $r\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Do you mind explaining to a slowpoke that from $3\geq m([-1,2])\geq m(\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(A+r))=\sum m(A)$ you are forced to conclude $m(A) = 0$? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the sum on the right. You are adding the same number over and over. If it is non-zero it must be positive, and the sum would be infinite. That can't be less than $3$.

Comment: It's a rather general question: How do you (or Bass the author) suddenly came up out of blue with $\mathbb Q$ in the proof? It happens all the time in math proof, especially in real analysis. If it were left to me, I wouldn't come up with it in a million years. Is it part of math-maturity package? Thanks again, but I am still digesting bit by bit...

Comment: That construction of the set $N$ is due to [Vitali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set). It is indeed ingenious, but like every idea, it is a combination of ideas coming from past experiences. At the time lots of people were working in defining length for all subsets of the real line and also studying the axiom of choice. The $\mathbb{Q}$ is yet more natural and old. The reals are constructed as the limit points of the rationals. So, all proofs about the reals can be written as statements about the rationals anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! Now I am able to work out a solution. Thanks again.